# Spawning an object on another player

Tags: swift3

I am trying to make a game about a knight that has a sword right now i just want to spawn a sword on him/right infant of him this is my code
        sword.position = player.position

```
      func swordAction(){
        addChild(sword)
        sword.removeFromParent()
}

func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        leftButton.name = "leftButton"
        rightButton.name = "rightButton"
        upButton.name = "upButton"
        downButton.name = "downButton"
        swordButton.name = "swordButton"
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        let node : SKNode = self.atPoint(location)
        if node.name! == "swordButton" {
            swordAction()
```